# JS Pricebreak Calculator. Find Array value from qty

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, vue.js, methods

## Hello, I am creating a screen print pricing calculator in vue.js

*Simplified version of the object I'm working with*

```
data() {
    return {
      qty: 0,
      breaks: [12, 24, 36, 100],
      matrix: [10, 9, 8, 7],
      pricePer: 0, 
      total: 0 // (pricePer * qty)
    };
},
```

I have an input that changes the qty value.
the "breaks" object is the quantity thresholds..

So if the user puts in a qty less than 12 (the first value in "breaks" array there should be an error because the minimum for screenprinting is 12

the "matrix" array is price per shirt

so I need a function that will

1. Take the quantity and find index of the nearest value in the breaks array
2. Use that index to find the price per shirt in the "matrix" array

---

When it's completely done there will be a lot more variables calculating the price.

*(qty, single / double sided, number of printed colors)*

but if I can just get an idea on how the function should be approached I should be able to apply it to the rest of the calculator.

This is my first time posting on here, thank you!!!

Comment: take a loop and check against the value of the break array. please add what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using vue.js, you could add the method under watchers. So you can have something like this

```
watch: {
  qty (val) {
    if (val > 11) {
      let res = 0;
      // The block gets the nearest value in the breaks array
      let arr = this.breaks;
      let diff = Math.abs(arr[0] - val);
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
        if (val == arr[i]) {
          res = i;
        }

        if (Math.abs(arr[i] - val) < diff) {
          res = i
        }
      }
      // Price per shirt will be the value at index of i
      let PPS = this.matrix[i];
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps